# Textarea contents character count different on Client and Server Site

Tags: html, servlets, textarea

We are debuging a legacy web application with max length validation on textarea fields written in plain Java Sctipt. The server site is Java Servlets with ISO-88597 encoding. The textareas have their wrap attribute as "hard".

If we have long text (that requires wrapping) in the text area like this:

[image]

While the **CLIENT** site reports the string to be 89 characters long, on form  submition, the length of the string is reported to be 91 chacacters long.  It seems like the browser has inserted a \r\n when wrapping the text, as shown below:

[image]

How do we get consistent character count on client site and server site?

Comment: Regex replace \r\n to \n in the counter

Comment: make sure character encoding is the same all the way through. Maybe there's an extra byte or two from UTF-8 to ISO-88597.... Another thing you could try is to change the content type that you are sending with